# Strange syntax in python dictionary construction - can you explain?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, syntax, defaultdict

I'm looking at someone else's Python code and saw the following expression:

```
dp = defaultdict(lambda: inf, {(): 0})
```

What does it mean?

I am familiar with defaultdict - `defaultdict(lambda: inf)` would create a dictionary with a default value of inf. But what about the second argument: `{(): 0}` ? What is its meaning?

EDIT:

I saw this line in the [following code](https://leetcode.com/problems/stickers-to-spell-word/discuss/475347/8-lines-Python-solution). So, I guess, I am trying to understand what is this good for. The author is not responsive so I am trying to understand the rationale and the potential benefits of using this syntax.

EDIT2: I realised that this line is simply equivalent to

```
dp = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
dp[()] = 0
```

The main advantage of this syntax is its shortness - it accomplishes this in a single line of code. I simply wasn't aware that you can define a defaultdict and, **simultaneously**, add an entry in it.

Now, the second argument in the constructor (using an empty tuple as a key for a dictionary entry) is still unusual. But it is just an odd choice - there is nothing new per se in this syntax.

PS. I accepted Patrick's post even as it is not providing the exact answer I was looking for. It still gave me some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a default dict with tuples of `(item:inf, {():0})`?

Why not simpy add one item and see for yourself?

```
from collections import defaultdict
from math import inf
dp = defaultdict(lambda: inf, {(): 0})

dp[42]
print(dp)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f5b389a7e18>, {(): 0, 42: inf})
```

---

Added a print statement to [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/stickers-to-spell-word/discuss/475347/8-lines-Python-solution) into the helper call

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from math import inf, isinf
from pprint import pprint

class Solution(object):
    def minStickers(self, stickers, target):
        s_cnts = *map(Counter, stickers),
        dp = defaultdict(lambda: inf, {(): 0})
        def helper(cnt):
            _id = tuple(cnt.items())
            if isinf(dp[_id]):
                dp[_id] = 1 + min((helper(cnt - s_cnt) for s_cnt in s_cnts 
                                  if s_cnt[_id[0][0]]), default=inf)
            pprint(dp)
            return dp[_id]

        # no python 3.8 available, replaced walrussoperator  
        return -1 if isinf( helper(Counter(target))) else helper(Counter(target))

s = Solution()

print(s.minStickers(["with", "example", "science"], "thehat"))
```

leads to

```
defaultdict(<function Solution.minStickers.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x03A4C4F8>,
            {(): 0,
             (('e', 1), ('a', 1)): inf,
             (('t', 1), ('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('a', 1)): inf,
             (('t', 2), ('h', 2), ('e', 1), ('a', 1)): inf})

defaultdict(<function Solution.minStickers.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x03A4C4F8>,
            {(): 0,
             (('a', 1),): inf,
             (('e', 1), ('a', 1)): inf,
             (('t', 1), ('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('a', 1)): inf,
             (('t', 2), ('h', 2), ('e', 1), ('a', 1)): inf})

defaultdict(<function Solution.minStickers.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x03A4C4F8>,
            {(): 0,
             (('a', 1),): 1,
             (('e', 1), ('a', 1)): inf,
             (('t', 1), ('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('a', 1)): inf,
             (('t', 2), ('h', 2), ('e', 1), ('a', 1)): inf})

defaultdict(<function Solution.minStickers.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x03A4C4F8>,
            {(): 0,
             (('a', 1),): 1,
             (('e', 1), ('a', 1)): 1,
             (('t', 1), ('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('a', 1)): inf,
             (('t', 2), ('h', 2), ('e', 1), ('a', 1)): inf})

defaultdict(<function Solution.minStickers.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x03A4C4F8>,
            {(): 0,
             The thread 'MainThread' (0x1) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
(('a', 1),): 1,
             (('e', 1), ('a', 1)): 1,
             (('t', 1), ('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('a', 1)): 2,
             (('t', 2), ('h', 2), ('e', 1), ('a', 1)): inf})

defaultdict(<function Solution.minStickers.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x03A4C4F8>,
            {(): 0,
             (('a', 1),): 1,
             (('e', 1), ('a', 1)): 1,
             (('t', 1), ('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('a', 1)): 2,
             (('t', 2), ('h', 2), ('e', 1), ('a', 1)): 3})
```

Comment: Thanks. I am probably trying to understand what is this good for. It seems that it has been used with a purpose. I added more details.

Comment: @Nick Wow - thats some convoluted thing. It creates Counter dicts for all the tickets and the target. The helper then creates all items() of the target Counter as key for the defaultdict. It then  uses any tickets which contains the 0th element of the current target`s Counteritems. wich then gets deducted from the current targets counter dict and recurses with the reduced target. Of all results they take the minimum. And all that with walruss operator to which I have to python available here - cant debug into it. Maybe some othercan shine a light on it.